# Rails: How to write correct POST integration test (without special testing frameworks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, post, integration-testing

I am trying to write a simple integration test in Rails (following suggestions of "Agile Web Development with Rails 4", Chapter 13.2) without frameworks such as Capybara, RSpec etc. . GET requests are straight forward and produce no errors, whereas POST causes trouble. I have two models "entries" and "items", where an item has many entries. I would like to POST an entry and the corresponding item was handed over as param. So I am trying the following:

```
post "/entries", entry: {item: items(:one), value: 12, date: '2015-09-15', min_quantity: 22000, max_quantity: 3000000, country_id: 1}
assert_template :show
```

This produces:

```
1) Failure:
...
expecting <"show"> but rendering with <["entries/_form", "entries/new", "layouts/application"]>
```

which tells me that no entry was created, because in this case the controller redirects to method new (scaffold standard). So, how can I correctly create an entry using POST. Some more details:

- I tried to leave out `item: items(:one)` since in the browser this needs not be submitted manually
- I checked the model - and in fact no entry was created
- I also produced a unit test to check on this very entry data and is passes
- `post_via_redirect` does no better

Does anyone see my problem or have an example for a POST integration test which corresponds to a simple form including one parameter which is programatically set upfront? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution: there is a slight difference between unit tests and integration tests. While in unit tests you can refer to the referenced model by `item: items(:one)` in integration tests you must be precise like `item_id: items(:one).id`, which is the exact name of the data field in the model and database.
The exact details behind the scenes I do not know - maybe someone can comment and further enlighten me.